# How to derive Cauchy Riemann Equations from partial differentiation with respect to $\bar{z}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be a complex function, where $z=x+iy$ and that we can always write $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, where $u$ and $v$ are real functions involving two independent variables.

Let $\bar{z}=x-iy$. (The complex conjugate of variable $z$)

If $f(z)$ is analytic (holomorphic) then it is obvious that the Cauchy Riemann conditions satisfy and we can derive them from standard definition of differentiation.

$\lim_{\Delta z\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(z+\Delta z)-f(z)}{\Delta z}$

(which is found in most of the books)

Put in another way holomorphic function satisfy $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}=0$ (That is holomorphic function does not involve the variable $\bar{z}$ and it involves only $z$)

In a video lecture I encountered that we can write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}=$  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ - $i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$ and by substituting $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ and then by equating real and imaginary parts we can derive Cauchy Riemann conditions.

My question is, "Is it correct to write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}=$  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ - $i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$"

If so,

1. Please explain $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}=$  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ - $i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$
2. How to proceed to derive the Cauchy Riemann Conditions from here?

Also it is said that $z$ and $\bar{z}$ are linearly independent of each other.

3)How they are linearly independent (or) what it precisely means?

Comment: Jack's [answer to another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2181189/26369) may help you understand the Wirtinger derivatives better on a basic level, and depending on your background, most of [my answer to an unrelated question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4071337/26369) might help you understand where they come from.

Comment: Wirtinger derivatives is what I have been searching for, which I never knew before. Thanks Mark S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what definitions you know, but I'll assume you know real calculus and linear algebra.

First, note that $z = x+iy = (1,1) \neq (1,-1) = x-iy =\overline{z}$, is direct the linear independence  of $z$ with $\overline{z}$ (definition of linear algebra: no exists a scalar such that $\lambda z =\overline{z}$). Even, as vectors of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ they form orthogonal directions.

By partial derivation of $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, i.e.,
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$
the above equality due to the uniqueness of the limit.

I define
\begin{equation*}
            f'(z)=f'(x,y)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,y)
        \end{equation*}
and

\begin{equation*}
            \begin{split}
                \frac{\partial}{\partial z}&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\\
                \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)
            \end{split}
        \end{equation*}
it is possible to verify that $f'(z)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}=0$ by C-R.

> The Cauchy - Riemann conditions hold if and only if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}=0$

**Proof:**
($\Leftarrow$) Let $f:U\subseteq\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}=0$, then:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)=0
\end{equation*}
then (using $f= u+iv$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
0=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(u+iv)+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(u+iv)
&=&\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+ 
   i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\\
&=&\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)+ 
   i\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
Then (separating in real and imaginary parts):
$$\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)=0$$
and
$$\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)=0$$

concluding C-R.

($\Rightarrow$) By a construction of $f'(z)$, assuming C-R. Then:
\begin{eqnarray*}
f'(z)=f'(x,y)
&=&\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,y)\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,y)\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,y)\right)
\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,y)\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(x,y)-i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y)\right)
\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,y)\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(x,y)-i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y)\right)
\\
&=&\dots\text{ sorting out, check it
 }\dots\\
&=&\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}
\end{eqnarray*}

But $f'(z) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}=0$.

> I recommend seeing
>
> 1. Stein. Shakarchi-Complex analysis. An Introduction - Princeton University.
> 2. J. Bak & D.Newman-Complex analysis (2010).
> 3. Alexander Isaev-Twenty one lectures on complex analysis (2017).
> 4. Walter Rudin-Real and complex analysis

Comment: I will be attentive in case you have any questions

Comment: I got clarified with linear independence and its very obvious. Can you just elaborate more on that chain rule. That 's were its hard for me to grasp.  I have adequate knowledge in multivariable calculus on real variable. Let me also elaborate where I got stuck. Say f is a function of (x,y,z) and each of these are functions of (say) r,s that is x,y and z are functions of r,s. I know to write chain rule of partial f with respect to r (or) with respect to s. But the variable z in the denominator of partial f with respect to z is a combination of x+iy. How does it work with partial derivative?

Comment: Hope you got me. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get you. And what is x, Yy . Or just explain two definitions just below the line "By chain rule (check it):" Or provide me some text book references that makes that clear.

Comment: @felics moses, I think "$x$ y $y$" is Spanish for "$x$ and $y$".

Comment: @MATorres Wirtinger derivatives is what I have been searching for, which I never knew before. You dint mention that But I got a clear explanation here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314863/what-is-the-intuition-behind-the-wirtinger-derivatives . Any way you helped me some way.Thanks

Comment: You can verify the link property from the demonstration of the second implication, it is a simple exercise, it is just reordering the terms